# setting textarea value in IE and FF

Tags: jquery, text, textarea

A demo for sharing data between an input (id=obHid) and a textarea (id=idField)

```
 if($.browser.msie)
  $("#"+idField).text($("#obHid").val()); // IE
 else
  $("#"+idField).attr("value", $("#obHid").val()); // FF
```

Iskrahelk,

Answer (score 2):

Don't use either of those methods, and especially don't use browser sniffing. Touching `$.browser` is almost always a mistake.

The proper way to read and write form field values in jQuery is `val()`. It doesn't matter whether the form field involved is an `<input type="text">` or a `<textarea>`, they'll both work the same.

```
$('#'+idField).val($("#obHid").val());
```

[Aside: however this will break if `idField` may contain dots, as in a selector string they'll turn into class selectors. If that's a concern just use the plain JavaScript version:

```
document.getElementById(idField).value= document.getElementById('obHid').value;
```

a bit wordier, but more straightforward.]